# List of evented / asynchronous languages

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, asynchronous, lisp

I'm working on a system than has to be pretty scalable from the beginning. I've started looking at / playing around with asynchronous/evented approaches to writing serverside code. I've played around with both ruby's EventMachine and node.js.

EventMachine is cool, but doesn't have asynchronous file I/O, which I need. The interface is kind of strange, too.

Node.js is awesome, but it's... uhh.. it's javascript.

Can the greater Stack Overflow community help me out by listing other languages that have strong asynchronous support? To qualify, the language would need to support both closures and have libraries for asynchronous file io, http, etc. It would be nice to have something like node.js that was written in a stronger language than javascript.

Lisp? Python has twisted, right?

Comment: What are you missing from JavaScript? If node.js works for you, don't discard it just because it's JavaScript.

Comment: Your "uhh.. it's javascript" comment suggests to me that you've rejected Node.js out of hand because of its past reputation rather than its present capabilities. It may or may not be the real solution you're looking for, but I think you should look a little deeper.

Comment: I'm just being silly. I actually grew up on javascript, but it can be VERY difficult to code anything large in it because of the weak object oriented support. I've been having a lot of fun with node.js, and definitely haven't rejected it yet, but if there's something that has better OO, that would be awesome

Comment: You might want to clarify want you mean by "better OO", too, then.  I think it fits with Alan Kay's concepts of messaging and late-binding a lot better than most other ostensibly "OO" languages out there.

Comment: From the Haskell website: "Abstractions are the key to building modular, maintainable programs, so much so that a good question to ask of any new language is "what mechanisms for abstraction does it provide?" - I think that abstracting is more difficult in javascript because it doesn't have native classes, exceptions, and namespaces, for one

Comment: I agree that abstractions are key, but it's not even clear to me that OO is a necessary abstraction.  And I certainly see no evidence that prototype-based OO is somehow worse than class-based OO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Erlang](http://erlang.org) may be the language with the highest intrinsic scalability for server-side code (it manages multiprocessing for you, mostly by doing async, cooperative task switching "under the covers") -- if you can stomach its peculiar syntax and (often) peculiar semantics.

Python has twisted (very general purpose for all networking tasks), tornado (for server-side async specifically), and stackless (widely used in MMP online games), not to mention the old but usable `asyncore` that's in the standard library (and the even-older "Medusa" that sits on top of asyncore to enrich its functionality).

[Go](http://golang.org/) has very light "stackless" `goroutines` and `channels` for synchronization purposes when needed.

Comment: What about [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/)? Isn't it another Python async IO library worth looking at?

Answer (score 16):

I would recommend that you take another look at [node.js](http://NodeJS.Org/). One of the biggest problems with using libraries to do event-based programming in an object-oriented programming language (rather than using an event-based programming language in the first place), is that usually all the *other* existing libraries are *not* event-based, and it is really awkward to mix event-based and synchronous I/O. In fact, it is pretty much impossible, or more precisely, it *is* possible but destroys all the benefits of using event-based I/O in the first place. (Note that pretty much any third-party library you use (and the libraries that *they* use, and so forth), including the standard and core libraries of the language itself, must be event-based, to actually reap the benefits. Otherwise, you'll spend most of your project's time writing asynchronous wrappers around existing libraries.)

Now, if using event-based libraries is such a bad thing, then why do I recommend node.js? Simple: ECMAScript doesn't *have* any synchronous I/O libraries (because of the simple fact that it doesn't have any I/O libraries *at all*), so the mixing problem simply doesn't arise. (Actually, it has *some* I/O libraries, like `XmlHttpRequest` or Web Sockets, but guess what: those are *already* all event-based.)

node.js implements all I/O libraries itself, all event-based, without backwards-compatibility or legacy requirements.

Otherwise, *every* language or platform has some event-based or asynchronous I/O libraries: Ruby has [EventMachine](http://RubyEventMachine.Com/) and [Rev](http://Rev.RubyForge.Org/), .NET has [Rx](http://MSDN.Microsoft.Com/devlabs/ee794896), the JVM has [NIO](http://Java.Sun.Com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/nio/), Unix systems have kqueue/epoll, C has [libev](http://Software.Schmorp.De/pkg/libev.html) and [libeio](http://Software.Schmorp.De/pkg/libeio.html) (on top of which node.js and Rev are built), Perl has [AnyEvent](http://Software.Schmorp.De/pkg/AnyEvent.html) (built on top of libev by the same author) and so on.

Comment: I'm really liking node.js more and more. The ability to import modules solves most of the abstraction problems. Are there any other systems like node designed asynchronously from the ground up?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess Lisp would actually be a good fit to create an asynch implementation since the language exists in many different dialects and situations, just like JavaScript. However I'm not aware of anyone that went through this hell job :-)

Answer (score 4):

F# has asynchronous workflows, which are a tremendous way to write async code.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have expressed interest in Lisp, you might want to consider [Clojure](http://clojure.org) - a Lisp dialect for the JVM with a strong focus on [concurrency](http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming). Pretty much anything can be run asynchronously by running it in an [agent](http://clojure.org/agents). Of course, it also provides [painless](http://clojure.org/java_interop) access to the entire Java ecosystem.